# How to ask for user input cotinuously after finishing one round of opetation?

Tags: python

i've got a python script that eliminates the print out of vowels inside a word (the ugly vowel eater). I meant to let the user input a new word once the previous word is examed. Please help me with that, i've attaced the code below.

Many thanks!

```
user_word = input("Please enter a word: ")
user_word = user_word.upper()

while True:
    if user_word != "END":
        for letter in user_word:
            if letter == "A":
                continue
            elif letter == "E":
                continue
            elif letter == "I":
                continue
            elif letter == "O":
                continue
            elif letter == "U":
                continue
            else:
                print (letter)
        
    break
    print ("Thanks for using the ugly vowel eater!")
```

Comment: So where do you want the new word to be taken as input?

Comment: If you want the user to input multiple times, wouldn't it make sense if the input was done *within* the loop?

Comment: put first two lines within the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:

    # take user input in the while loop
    user_word = input("Please enter a word: ")
    user_word = user_word.upper()

    if user_word != "END":
        for letter in user_word:
            if letter == "A":
                continue
            elif letter == "E":
                continue
            elif letter == "I":
                continue
            elif letter == "O":
                continue
            elif letter == "U":
                continue
            else:
                print (letter)

    # make use of else clause to terminate loop only when END was given as input
    else:
        break
    print ("Thanks for using the ugly vowel eater!")
```